# npm:relocation error: /lib64/libnode.so.93: symbol FIPS_selftest, version OPENSSL_1_1_0g not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

Tags: node.js, npm, centos7, yarn-v2

after installing nodejs, npm and yarn via yum install command whenever I try to run npm command I get the following error

```
node: relocation error: /lib64/libnode.so.93: symbol FIPS_selftest, version OPENSSL_1_1_0g not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
```

This is happening on CentOS 7 with the latest updates installed.

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

I searched the web for this error and I cannot find anything relevant and so far this is happening on my 5th server.

I tried removing nodejs, npm and yarn and even installing older versions but with no results. Also I tried removing openssl and again that didn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered a similar problem. I found out that it is because I have the source code of another version 1.1.1 of openssl in my system, and the version installed in the system is 1.0.2; and I set the program runtime library file search path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `1.1.1` version openssl source code path, because the versions before and after openssl are incompatible, when the system runs npm, it automatically finds the 1.1.1 version of openssl according to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path, so an error is reported.
Solution: export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""` to let the program automatically find the version of openssl installed on the system

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when installing NODE JS on CENTOS 7 after installing OPENSSL 1_1_1.
I spent 4 days looking for solutions.
What worked for me: installing nodejs version 16.11.1 which does not require OPENSSL_1_1_0g

```
sudo yum install curl -y 

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc

nvm install 16.11.1
```

---

Installing alternative versions through configuration did not help:

./config -Wl,-rpath="/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e/lib" -Wl,--enable-new-dtags --prefix="/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e" --openssldir="/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e/ssl"

Did not help:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e/lib"

Did not help:
adding to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
these lines
/usr/local/openssl/lib
/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e/lib
and executing the command
ldconfig -v

Did not help:
echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl_OpenSSL_1_1_1e/lib" >> /etc/environment